# Android Listing Problem

Tags: android, listview

I just started Android programming. I have a `ListView` with an image and some text and I want to change the image when clicked, but the problem is I cannot identify which image is clicked because I am using the same image id and only changing the source.

How can I solve this problem?

My `ListView` is based on `LazyAdapter` class model.

Comment: The answer is in the question: generate a different id per image!

Answer (score 0):

If you load the images at runtime, assign an id to each image as you add them.

You can also traverse the list of images by getting the images parent view's children, then check if the image clicked is the same image as the one in the onClick-event.

Comment: sorry. i cannot understand . can you explain with example code ?